# multiple html-objects with shared width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to generate a diff of two files, and the output is a html-file. The differences are grouped in boxes, currently I'm using `<ul>` with a slightly changed color for this purpose.

My aim is that the colored boxes **all have the same width**, but it should be the **minimum possible** for still showing the whole content. When I let them all take the smallest possible width, all boxes have a different size, which looks really awfull, but I don't want them to stretch unneccessarily to the width of my Content-div.

That's how it currently looks:
[image]

The css-piece looks like this: 
`ul.inBox {background-color: #FEFEFE; list-style-type:none; padding-left: 1em; padding-right: 1.8em;`

My idea was to put the whole thing into a table column, so that the column has a minimum width and all blocks use the maximum possible width inside this column, but I wanted to know if someone knows a better solution.

Comment: Only doable with javascript

Comment: I dont really want to use javascript...
Do you think the idea with the column wont work?

Comment: Like i said, only doable with javaschript ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this demo helpful for you..the width is totally depend on the width of text. As the text amount will increase the width will be. Check the [Demo](http://jsbin.com/qecalina/2/).

```
ul {
  padding:0; margin:5px;
  list-style:none;
  background:gold;
  display:table;
  width: auto;
  min-width: 25%; /*Added minimum width*/
  }
```

In HTML I put many `ul` as per this case.

```
 <ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  </ul>
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
</ul>

  <ul>
  <li>Item 1 ITem 2</li>
  <li>Item 2 can be more longer;   </li>
  </ul>
    <ul>
<li>Item 2 can be more longer; Item 2 can be more longer</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: sorry, maybe I didnt express my problem detailled enough. I want that all 4 `<ul>` in your example have the same width

Comment: @FlorianKoch I've modified my answer. now all ul have min-width by default. and as per content the width will be increased. let me know if this solution work for you.. will be happy to help you.

Comment: it works for me, and though it's not quite the way i wanted it to be it also helps because this could be a neat solution if I dont use my original idea
So I'll upvote, but don't accept (:

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you are looking for max-width. Following code:

```
ul.inBox {
    ... (you properties)
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px; /*here you define you width*/
}
```

Comment: sorry, this is not solving my problem, because I don't want it to be cut at 300px, I want that all my `<ul>` or `<div>` share the same width, which is determined by the one with the biggest width

Comment: you want to put several `<ul>` inside a div? If so, work with percentage `max-width: 50%`

Comment: I really dont know how to express it better, so maybe a example might help:
Lets say i have 4 different `ul` with content of different length.
Every `<ul>` is independent from the others.
Still, I want them to all have the same width, which is determined by the one whose content is the longest/biggest.

Comment: Beauty, then the parent div can have the size you want. Only the `<ul>` should work with percentage. For example if you use four `<ul>` `max-width` would have `25%`. Get it?

Answer (score 0):

I'll put in a practical way what you want.

Your Html

```
<div class="master">
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>item1</li>
        <li>item2</li>
        <li>item3</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Your CSS

```
.master ul {
    ... (you properties)
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%; /*here you define you width*/
}
```

As you can see  are within div.master getting it proportional to size.

Bye.

Comment: ok i'll try as soon as i can, atm only online with smartphone. If it works I'll upvote and accept

Comment: sorry, but this wont work for me... See: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yiluvoxa/1/edit)

Comment: @Florian Kock I saw your example, try putting these properties. `.master ul {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 25%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
}`